# No se ha declarado el atributo 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:Layout_centerInParent'

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

Estoy empezando en esto de desarrollar apps para android en Xamarin y en una declaración de un progressbarr me aparece dicho error. ¿Es vital corregirlo? ¿Cómo debe solucionarse de ser así?

código

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:weightSum="100">
<TextView
    android:text="Create an account"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textColor="#368DEB"
    android:id="@+id/txtCreateAccount"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="25sp" />
<Button
    android:text="Sing In"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="15"
    android:id="@+id/btnSingIn"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:text="Or"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="15"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/txtOr"
    android:gravity="center" />
<Button
    android:text="Sing Up with Email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="15"
    android:id="@+id/btnSingUp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="35"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" /> <!--Aquí aparece el error "No se ha declarado el atributo " http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:Layout_centerInParent"-->
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: En donde te muestra ese mensaje?

Comment: Oh, no se actualizó mi pregunta :'(. Bueno, aparece en el atributo "android:layout_centerInParent" del progressbar

Comment: Que versión de Visual Studi usas? 9, 12, 14?

Comment: La más reciente, la 14

Comment: Entonces descarga los archivos que indico y copialos dentro de : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Xml\Schemas

Comment: ¿Y si no tengo los directorios, los  creo?

Comment: Espera, los encontré pero están en otro directorio dentro de VS 14.0,¿ los coloco ahí?

Comment: Dentro de /Xml/Schemas

Comment: Ya coloqué los archivos en el directorio, pero aún me sigue marcando el error en el atributo :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que usas Xamarin, la propiedad debe estar en el Android SDK pero usando Xamarin no se contiene, te sugiero descargues los archivo que indico y que contienen esta y otras propiedades :

[**android-layout-xml.xsd**](https://github.com/atsushieno/monodroid-schema-gen/blob/master/android-layout-xml.xsd)

[**schemas.android.com.apk.res.android.xsd**](https://github.com/atsushieno/monodroid-schema-gen/blob/master/schemas.android.com.apk.res.android.xsd)

copialos dentro del folder `/Xml/Schemas` de tu VS:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tengo este mismo problema, y esta solucion me ha ayudado un poco, pero lo que me falla son las librerias de http://schemas.android.com/tools. Dónde puedo encontrar dichos ficheros para agregarlos del mismo modo?